# Compare 2 pandas.DataFrames, get differences and print only rows that changed from the first one

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes which I am comparing with below snippet:

```
df3 = pandas.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

It works fine, it compares both and as an output I got rows that are different form both of them.

What I would like to achieve is to compare 2 dataframes to get rows that are different but as an output only get/keep rows from the first DataFrame.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `~isin()`:

```
df.set_index(list(df.columns), inplace=True)
df2.set_index(list(df2.columns), inplace=True)
df[~df.index.isin(df2.index)].reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pre-mark the df's rows with a number (like `.assign(mark=1)`) and drop the helper column after

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 10, 20)) # dummy data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 10, 20)) # dummy data

df3 = pd.concat([df1.assign(mark=1), df2.assign(mark=2)]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df3[df3['mark'].eq(1)].drop(columns='mark'))
```

Prints:

```
    0
2  -6
3  -8
14  3
16 -3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the unique rows from the first dataframe, you really want a left join.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on='your_column_here', 
                   how='left', indicator=True)
```

Now you can check the `_merge` column and filter for left only:

```
    col1    col2    _merge
0      1      10    both
1      2      11    both
2      3      12    both
3      4      13    left_only
4      5      14    left_only
5      3      10    left_only
```

Comment: In your answer, I have to specify the column right? The issue is, that values may differ in different columns and in my DFs there are 14 columns